# С чего начать, если знаешь делфи?

Tags: java

С чего начать изучение Java? Как установить? Простейшие примеры?

Comment: Обратите внимание на [вопросы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&java/).

Comment: [Изучение java](http://hashcode.ru/questions/16644/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-java)

Answer (score 2):

Я занимаюсь программирование уже 12 лет, несмотря на то что мне всего 20. Работаю ведущим программистом АСУ ТП. И постоянно читаю всякую литературу в свободное время. Зная 1 язык более менее углубленно, перепрыгнуть на другой не составляет особого труда. В свое время я открыл C++ и понеслось C#, PHP, Java, Javascript, Basic. Вот только с Asm были проблемы. Все в твоих руках. А рекомендую книги автор которых Герберт Шилдт. С 0 полного начинаешь. Только читая ее не перелистывай страницы с умным видом мол "А это ерунда, все понятно!!!". Потому как в промеж строк найдешь много полезной информации.

Answer (score 0):

Языки,синтаксисы разные....

Переменные, константы, массивы и всё остальное - это одинаково. Это и есть программирвоание.

2 язык учить легче,т. к. тебе уже понятно большинство терминов и способов их применения.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте сначала java code convention, а после этого можно читать и Шилдта, и Хорстмана, и другие фундамментальные вещи.